# Combine data from variable amount of datasets into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries which return me a identical amount of `c_id`s (amount is variable)

```
SELECT c_id FROM test WHERE test_id=123 AND op=1

SELECT c_id FROM test WHERE test_id=123 AND op=2
```

---

**Example:**

First query returns 1, 3, 5, 7

Second query returns 2, 4, 6, 8

The corresponding ids are:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

---

With these `c_id`s I want to use this query:

```
SELECT a.offset, a.values, b.value
FROM data AS a INNER JOIN data AS b  ON a.offset=b.offset
AND a.c_id=RESULTS FROM FIRST QUERY ABOVE
AND b.c_id=RESULTS FROM SECOND QUERY ABOVE
```

My expected result should look like this:

```
offset where c_id=1    Data where c_id=1     Data where c_id=2
.
.
.
offset where c_id=3    Data where c_id=3     Data where c_id=4
.
.
offset where c_id=5    Data where c_id=5     Data where c_id=6
.
.
.
.
offset where c_id=7    Data where c_id=7     Data where c_id=8
.
.
.
.
.
```

The amount of data the corresponding `c_id`s return are equal

How can I achieve that? It is like a `UNION ALL` with all the `c_id`s, but I have no idea how to do that...

Comment: Do you require the same value as indicated in your expected result

Comment: @StackUser. I am not sure if I understood you right. The `c_id`s are in chronological order (like it is shown in the example) but they aren't constant.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a:

```
SELECT a.offset, a.values, b.value
FROM data AS a INNER JOIN data AS b  ON a.offset=b.offset
AND a.c_id IN (SELECT c_id FROM test WHERE test_id=123 AND op=1)
AND b.c_id IN (SELECT c_id FROM test WHERE test_id=123 AND op=2)
```

Comment: Is it certain that the data are returned in the order I described above?

Comment: There's no certainty with an sql query unless you specify an `order by`